# How to create youtube-like seekbar preview images for HTML video

Tags: html5-video

For many of the videos on Youtube, if one hovers over the seekbar, a small image will pop up reflecting the frame at about that place in the video.

Is there some way to create this if using an HTML video element?

Comment: I use plyr.io for projects as it has great support for this (and a great player to 'skin'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thumbnails are actually typically contained in a separate media stream or 'track' that is created on the server side and delivered as part of the streamed video.

The client downloads this stream and when a user seeks, it displays the thumbnail image that is closest to the time the user is seeking to.

You can see a good example of how the player handles this with the dash.js reference player:

- https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/latest/samples/thumbnails/thumbnails.html

Generating the thumbnails on the fly on the browser would require the video to be delivered, decoded and a frame displayed at the point the user was seeking to which is typically too much to do in the time available to be practical for streamed videos.

Comment: Thanks, very useful.  I did a lot of searching for something exactly like this, but apparently wasn't using the correct terms.  I will look into how create the thumbnail track.